# Three or more backgrounds stacked CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to have three backgrounds stacked under each other using CSS but only two appear at maximum. Basically I want to make something like this:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
body{
  font-size: 100%;
  background-image: url(ex1.png), url(ex2.png), url(ex3.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this result using the body or am I forced to use divs instead?

Comment: Why are you putting both second and third image URLs within the same `url()`? And you have no `background-position` setting so they will start at the same position (one below the other)

Comment: My bad! Editting it right now!

Comment: Even if I do that I only get two at maximum under each other, is three even possible using this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set multiple images on a single element without specifying the `background-position`, they all are placed on the same position and so they will be one below the other. As long as the images are of the same size only one will show. If the images are of different size, say first is 100px tall, second is 200px, third is 300px then for the first 100px the first image will show up, for 100 - 200px the bottom of second image will show and for 200-300px the last third of the final image will show up.

Here is how you can stack the images within a single element.

- If all three images are same height then just mention `background-position: top,center,bottom`. This setting means the top of the first image will be aligned with top of the container, second one's center will be aligned with center of container and third one's bottom will be at container's bottom.
- If the images are of different height then the above approach will not work as-is, the positions will have to be set in actual pixels values such that the position of the second and subsequent image are offset by the sum total of heights of previous image. So, the `background-position` should be like `0px 0px, 0x [height of image1], 0px [height of image1 + height of image2]`. This can still be done with percentages (to make it work for image of any size) but it would need algebraic equations to be used because of how background-positioning with percentages works.

Note: Height of the element should be equal to the height of all three images put together for all of them to show up completely.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid;
  }
.bg-stack-with-pos {
  background-position: top, center, bottom;
}
.bg-stack-without-pos-diff-height {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/200/nature/2), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/300/nature/3);
}
.bg-stack-with-pos-diff-height {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/200/nature/2), url(http://lorempixel.com/100/300/nature/3);
  background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 100px, 0px 300px;

}
```

```html
<h3>Stacked Images with Background Position - One below the other</h3>
<div class='bg-stack-with-pos'></div>
<h3>Stacked Images w/o Background Position - One behind the other</h3>
<div class='bg-stack-without-pos'></div>
<h3>Stacked Images w/o Background Position and different heights - One below the other</h3>
<div class='bg-stack-with-pos-diff-height'></div>
<h3>Stacked Images w/o Background Position and different heights - One behind the other</h3>
<div class='bg-stack-without-pos-diff-height'></div>
```

Comment: `background-position: top, center, bottom;` is sufficient since the container fits the image widths.

Comment: Thank you for adding the additional explanation as well, it makes a lot more sense in my head now :)